# Can i trust on a key generation process without check for duplicates?

Tags: php, key, probability, probability-theory

I'm using a process to put a name on user profile images and i'm afraid of collisions.
The name pattern that i'm using is the following:

9999999_9999999_9999999

So the images are named like:

**4533381_1284948_8023255.jpg**

The range to the integer is from *1.000.000* to *9.999.999*
Is necessary to check if a image with the same name already exists on user profile images directory? (assuming that all the images resides on the same directory level).

The integers are generated using the php function `mt_rand(1000000,9999999);`

Comment: read up about the [birthday paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem). you'll be surprised at how quickly the odds of a collision grow. YOu shouldn't be making "random" filenames. use something deterministic - e.g. a salted sha1 hash of the user's ID will be far far far far more unique than your "random" number.

Comment: db, auto-incremented unique id perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probability of a collision is very low in your case (though possible).

- Counting all possible values of image name: `(9999999-1000000+1)^3 == 7.29 * 10^20`. 
   
  *Hint:* you may increase this value by generating numbers between `0` and `9999999` and left-padding them with zeros while converting to strings, e.g.: `sprintf("%07d", $number)`
- `mt_rand` is a relatively good random generator.

A collision will *probably* never happen.

---

However, if it's easy in your app's context, you may implement the check that the name is unoccupied, and if it's not, just re-generate random name in the same way.

A kind of `do { $name = generate_name(); } while(is_occupied($name));` loop.

---

Note that this solution **is safer than deterministic hashing** proposed in comments.

The reason is that hash collisions are possible as well, and if it happens, then you're done — it's deterministic and you have no possibility to generate another random.

Or you have to use a *chain of hash functions* for the case of collisions. This means a similar do-while loop, but slightly more complex, involving data which the hash is calculated on and a counter (which affects hash calculation). More code with no benefits, IMO.

Comment: This is the exactly type of explanation that i was looking for. I don't want to tie the imagens to user_id because the user can change those images and i'll have problem with browser cash and a lot of others problems that runs away from the question. I think that if the number of images do not exceed ~25 billion (acording to birthday paradox) i'll have no problems with this method. Thank's for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: No.

Long answer: Even with a 32 digit random string of numbers and letters, you will eventually possibly hit a collision. As someone commented, you should try to use something related to the user, such as their user ID, and hash it using some form of hasher.

See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) for hashing in PHP.